# How to leave "${txt}" in configure_file of cmake?

Tags: cmake, tcl, keyword

I have CMakeLists.txt file  and line in it:

```
configure_file ( script.tcl.in script.tcl )
```

cmake changes successfully headers where I need but there is a block in file *script.tcl.in* with such lines:

```
set list "1 2 3"
set line "param "
foreach a $list{
  line = ${line}_$a
}
```

In this block, I want to get string "param _1_2_3".

After starting *cmake* I get file *script.tcl* but it substitutes *${line}*  by none because ${smth} is a parameter in cmake:

```
set list "1 2 3"
set line "param "
foreach a $list{
  line = _$a
}
```

The problem is that both *cmake* and *tcl* use the same format ${var} for getting value of a variable *var*. So, the question is what I have to do to get this block as it is in  *script.tcl.in* file?

Answer (score 2):

Passing `@ONLY` option to `configure_file` forces CMake to not touch `${...}` expressions but substitute only `@VAR@` ones.

```
configure_file ( script.tcl.in script.tcl @ONLY)
```

If a symbol `@` has no special meaning for the specific scripting language (for which you are preparing the script), using `@ONLY` is a valuable approach.

Answer (score 0):

A possible *workaround* is to generate the substitution in Tcl using `format`:

```
line = [format "%s_%s" $line $a]
```

(The rest of that line looks *really* suspicious to me; Tcl uses the `set` command for assignment, not an inline `=` operator. And you appear to have another syntax problem on the previous line too.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Realy, It's not my code in Tcl. I don't write in Tcl and don't know why the author wrote so. I'm writing building procedure with cmake for the project.

Comment: Yes, its my fault. Original code  is "set line ${line}_$a". Your variant works. Thank you again.